# Can't add Global.asax file to WCF project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

I have an webservice made with WCF, used this getting started tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730935(v=vs.110).aspx.

Using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

When using Add Item on the project, and searching for the Global.asax file, I can't find it, it's not in Web>General or anywhere. The only way I could add it is to create the file manually and then adding existing item but enabling the open file window to show all files. Obviously this doesn't work, there is no code behind or anything.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

If i understood our question you can find it under **Web** with the name of **"Global Application Class"**

[image: Global.asax]

Comment: No, it's not there. That's the point of the question. I've created a new project as a WCF Service through New>Website, instead of New>Project>WCF Service Library, which is what the tutorial did. Now in this project there is an global.asax, but not in the original, and the cors configuration which can be done in the asax file I have to do it in a less desirable way (in the service code).

Comment: Are you searching Global.asax in WCF project or in Project which is cosuming WCF. You cant get it in WCF project. and if you want to add it in WCF then i have a question why?